# How to convert int to Double in C programming

Tags: c, types, casting, operator-precedence

```
int num1, num2;
```

`double average;`

```
average=(double)(num1+num2)/2;
printf("average: %d", average);
```

My test printf shows average as: 0

This is maybe too easy, but I can't see it. My inputs are both "int" and the average is "double" but somehow it is not calculating right ?

Comment: The shortest way:  `average=(num1+num2)/2.;`

Comment: A tip to improve efficiency:  Enable all compiler warnings.  Certainly a warning about `printf("average: %d", average);` should have occurred.  Faster than posting on SO.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're using the wrong format specifier to `printf`.

The `%d` format specifier expects an `int` argument, but you're passing a `double`.  Using the wrong format specifier invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

To print a `double`, use `%f`.

```
printf("average: %f\n", average);
```

Comment: ```f``` means float while ```lf``` means double

Comment: @Supergamer Not for `printf`.  Because it is a variadic function, any `float` argument will automatically get promoted to `double`.

Answer (score 4):

No need to modify the statement `average=(double)(num1+num2)/2;` to get expected result inside `printf` use `%f` instead of `%d`

- 1st `(num1+num2)` is performed, result of this is of `integral` type. lets say `15`. Next when you do `(double)15/2` result is of `floating` type which is `7.500000`.
- from previous step `average = (double)7.500000` average holds `7.500000` but since you printed in `%d` you are getting `0` as its undefined behavior. instead use `%f`

Here is the working one

```
int main() {
        int num1 = 7, num2 = 8;
        double average;
        average = (double)(num1 + num2)/2;
        printf("average: %f\n", average);
        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
int num1, num2;
double average;
average=(num1+num2)/2.;            // Using a decimal point forces 2 to be a double.
printf("average: %f\n", average);  // Use the correct specifier for double: %f
```

Answer (score 2):

Integer division yields an integer result: `1/2 == 0`, `5/3 == 1`, etc.  If you want a floating point result, at least one of the operands must be a floating-point type: `1/2.0f == 0.5f`, `5/3.0 == 1.6667`, etc.

So, you'll want to divide your sum by `2.0`, not `2`:

```
average = (num1 + num2)/2.0;
```

Secondly, you need to use the `%f` format specifier for floating-point output:

```
printf( "average: %f\n", average );
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use printf("average= %f",avearge); instead of using "%d" to print the average value.I think it will solve your issues...

Answer (score 0):

If you want a floating point result, at least one of the operands must be a floating-point type

This is my solution:

```
average = (num1 + num2)/(double)2;
```

---

```
printf ("Value of 1/2 is: %.4f\n", (double)(1/2));
// Value of 1/2 is: 0.0000

printf ("Value of 1/2 is: %.4f\n", (1/(double)2));
// Value of 1/2 is: 0.5000
```

Comment: This answer is not unique and doesn't really add anything to the answers already given to the OP.